# How do I update a dictionary using dict.update()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I am trying to add and update keys and values to a dictionary (stuff) using dict.update() but it isn't updating the dictionary. The following code just displays the initial dictionary twice.

```
stuff = {'rope': 1, 'torch': 6, 'gold coin': 42, 'dagger': 1, 'arrow': 12}

def displayInventory(inventory):
    print('Inventory:')
    for k, v in inventory.items():
        print(str(v)+' '+k)
        
displayInventory(stuff)
print('Total number of items: ' + str(sum(stuff.values())))

dragonLoot={'gold coin': 42, 'rope': 1}
dragonLoot.update(stuff)
print("Dragon's loot added: 42 gold coins and 1 rope")
displayInventory(dragonLoot)
print('Total number of items: ' + str(sum(dragonLoot.values())))
```

Comment: That does work, you just can't tell because you're updating the keys to the *same value*. Are you expecting the values to be *added*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.update()` doesn't quite work that way. I've made a function that will work though. Leave a comment if you have any questions.

```
stuff = {'rope': 1, 'torch': 6, 'gold coin': 42, 'dagger': 1, 'arrow': 12}

def displayInventory(inventory):
    print('Inventory:')
    for k, v in inventory.items():
        print(str(v)+' '+k)

def updateInventory(inventory,loot):
    for item in loot:
        if item in inventory:
            inventory[item] += loot[item]
        else:
            inventory[item] = loot[item]
    return inventory
    
displayInventory(stuff)
print('Total number of items: ' + str(sum(stuff.values())))

dragonLoot={'gold coin': 42, 'rope': 1}
stuff = updateInventory(stuff,dragonLoot)
print("Dragon's loot added: 42 gold coins and 1 rope")
displayInventory(stuff)
print('Total number of items: ' + str(sum(stuff.values())))
```